# Understanding a makefile for kernel creation

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have basic idea about writing makefiles. But I am finding it difficult to understand this makefile.

```
SOURCES=boot.o main.o

CFLAGS=-nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector
LDFLAGS=-Tlink.ld
ASFLAGS=-felf

all: $(SOURCES) link

clean:
    -rm *.o kernel

link:
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o kernel $(SOURCES)

.s.o:
    nasm $(ASFLAGS) $<
```

My folder contains `main.c`, `boot.asm`, `link.ld` files.

**Q1.** Why there is no command written to generate `main.o` from `main.c` and `boot.o` from `boot.asm` ?

**Q2.** What does the last lines signify ?

> .s.o:
>          nasm $(ASFLAGS) $<

**Q3** `CFLAGS` are defined at the top, but not used anywhere!? Are they taken into account automatically on compilation ?

**Q4** There is no command written for conversion from source code to `.o` files anywhere. The makefile works fine though and generates the required executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q2: this is a rule that generates a `.o` from a `.s` (assembly source file).

Q1: because it's covered by the rule I just explained.

Q4: there's the `.s.o` rule, and `make` has a [built-in rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) for compiling C modules.

Q3: the aforementioned rule for creating a `.o` from a `.c` takes `CFLAGS` into account.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please also explain what does `.s.o` signify here ?

Comment: @AmitTomar: generate `.o`, from `.s`. I'll add some links to the answer.